# Why am I getting error 'Invalid float value' when trying to pass float variable as argument to subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python script which takes multiple arguments. I want to run this script with different value of arguments. I have written the following code for a trial run but I am getting an error:

```
L1=[9,10,11]

import subprocess


for L in L1:
    subprocess.call(['python', r'C:\Users\priyajit\Downloads\lattice_qm_mc.py', 'e', '-l L', '-p'])
```

And the error is:

```
usage: lattice_qm_mc.py [-h] [-a A] [-cfg CFG] [-cor COR] [-d D] [-e E] [-i]
                        [-l L] [-mu MU] [-o] [-p] [-r R] [-t T] [-v {s,c,w}]
                        {e,m,w}
lattice_qm_mc.py: error: argument -l: invalid float value: ' L'
```

Default value of `l` is 10 and it takes float value.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the string "L" and you want to pass the variable L. Try:

```
import subprocess

L1=[9,10,11]

for L in L1:
    subprocess.call(['python', r'C:\Users\priyajit\Downloads\lattice_qm_mc.py', 'e', '-l', L, '-p'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass L incorrectly. Right now you're passing the string "L" instead of the values of the list L1.

Try this:

```
subprocess.call(['python', r'C:\Users\priyajit\Downloads\lattice_qm_mc.py', 'e', '-l', str(L), '-p'])
```

There we have separated the -l parameter and used str(L) to convert the actual value L from the list from integer to string, since subprocess.call expects strings as arguments.